# How does gravity work without consumption of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

To move any stationary object a force has to be applied and applying force needs energy. So how are objects pulled towards each other by gravity without any use of energy?

Answer (score 1):

Your premise that no energy is involved is false. Two point masses, with masses $M$ and $m$, separated by a distance $r$, have a gravitational energy associated with them given by: $$ U=-{GMm\over r} $$

Comment: Where does that energy come from?

Comment: That energy *is* gravity. It doesn't really "come from" anywhere: it is just a mathematical way of expressing the fact that objects with mass fall towards each other.

Comment: @Hark   Present potential energies, all the energy of the universe , was provided at the original big bang .  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang  . It is more complicated due to General relativity where energy conservation is not a law, but after nucleosynthesis the models that are based on the standard models of particle , nuclear, and classical physics fit all the data. So the statement  "from the big bang" holds.